# $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},\tau)$ s.t $f(x)=8$, $ \tau$ is any topology. Find the topology on the domain that is induced by $f$ and $ \tau$

Tags: general-topology

My attempt:

Let $\tau_0$ be the induced Topology, $\tau_0$ is the smallest topology  on the domain on f is $\mathbb{R}$. Consider:
$\{f^{-1}(b): b\in \tau\}\subset \tau_0.$
$f^{-1}(b) = \left\{  \begin{array}{ll}   \emptyset & \mbox{if } 8\notin b\\   \mathbb{R}& \mbox{if }  8\in b\end{array} \right.$.
Can we conclude that the induced topology $\tau_0=\{\emptyset,\mathbb{R} \}$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct: $\varnothing$ and $\Bbb R$ must belong to $\tau_0$, $\{\varnothing,\Bbb R\}$ is a topology on $\Bbb R$, and you’ve shown that continuity of $f$ does not require that $\tau_0$ include any other subsets of $\Bbb R$. A full answer would point out all of this, however.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, are there other ways to prove this?

Comment: I can’t think of any essentially different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Given that $f$ is the constant map with value $8$, it’s quite clear that whatever topology you put on the domain or the codomain, $f$ will be continuous. As you rightly point out, the inverse image of *any* set $B$ under $f$ will either be $\Bbb R$ or $\emptyset$ and these are in *any* topology on the domain.

So the coarsest topology on the domain that makes $f$ continuous (often called the induced topology by $f$, or rather (my preferred term) the *initial* topology induced by $f$) is indeed the indiscrete one ($\{\emptyset, \Bbb R\}$), because it works and *is* by definition a subset of any topology, and (dually) we also have that the *finest* topology on the codomain that makes $f$ continuous (the quotient topology or final topology induced by $f$ and any topology on the domain) is the discrete one. It seems you’re interested in the former mostly.